# Negative lookahead regex query for Solr

Tags: regex

I have two regexes that are similar. I would like to be able to query solr and get specific results for each regex. I cannot do a negative lookahead since this regex is being fed into Solr. And, unfortunately, the regex is being used for other things, so inject Solr-like operators is also not allowed.

#### Note

We also use these regexes in code for other things, so I cannot put `lucene` specific commands in the regex. That would make my life much easier!

Comment: Can you provide examples of sample input and expected output?

Comment: If it is for Lucene engine, try `.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*&~(xyz.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*)` as the first regex

Comment: what does &~ mean?

Comment: In Lucene engine, `&` is an AND operator and `~` is a COMPLEMENT operator.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, that will not work, `And, unfortunately, the regex is being used for other things, so inject Solr-like operators is also not allowed`.

Comment: I am not suggesting any Solr like operators. This is a single string above. A regex is a string.So, in your supplied code, use `{"regex": ".*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*&~(xyz.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*)", "attr1": "att1", "attr2": "att2"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(xyz.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*)|(.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*)`

Note that regex will usually attempt to match based on the given order of your inputs; if you've got a greedy regex that's consuming a more specific one, oftentimes, you can solve the issue simply by putting the specific one in front of the greedy one. As long as you're not trying to overlap the two regexes and search both at once for a given string, this should work fine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFnnTa/2)

Comment: so the regex that you show will match any `xyz...` strings (as in your demo), do you know what I can use to match anything like the `abc` example in your demo but not match the `xyz` strings?

Comment: Sure! By changing the first option to a negative lookahead, you can forbid a match of that format. `(?!xyz.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*)(^.*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*$)` uses a negative lookahead (not lookbehind!) and continues to match the `abc`-like strings, but specifically no longer matches any `xyz` strings. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YURAhe/1/)

Comment: But Solr (Lucene) doesn't handle negative lookaheads.

Comment: @Mark without lookaheads, that's a good deal more difficult to do. I suppose you could do something like `(^[^x].*-cd-uvw-f[0-9]+-b[0-9]+-t1-r[0-9]+.*$)`, which forces the first character to not be the letter `x`. According to the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YURAhe/2/), this solution works, but it also obviously loses a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I realize that that looses flexibility, but I fear that I am stuck with this solution.

Comment: It does not *lose* flexibility, it is a wrong pattern for the given requirements.